# I got correct reversed string in method but when i returned into main() it is showing wrong string as output

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package revstring;

/**
 *
 * @author Pawan
 */
public class RevString {

    private String substr="";
    private String temp="";
    private static int strLength=0;
    private String reversed="";

   public String revString(String str)
    {
        Character ch;

        strLength=str.length();
        System.out.println("length- "+strLength);

        if(strLength!=0)
        { 
            ch=str.charAt(strLength-1);          
            temp=temp+ch;                        
            substr=str.substring(0,strLength-1); 
            if(substr.equals("")){reversed=temp; return reversed;}
            return temp+revString(substr);  
        }
        return reversed;         
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       RevString rev=new RevString();
       System.out.println("reversed string- "+rev.revString("PAWAN"));
    }


}
```

Comment: You code gives me this output `length- 5
length- 4
length- 3
length- 2
length- 1
reversed string- NNANAWNAWANAWAP`

Answer (score 2):

Try [StringBuffer#reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse%28%29) built-in reverse method.

```
String str= "reverse";
StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer(str);
//reverse
String result= sb.reverse().toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

---

On the other side, the problem in your code is that you have are your class members that should have been method variables, which means you have **too many states**. Exactly the `temp` variable is the problem. To fix it, add this line to the beginning of your method:

```
 public String revString(String str)
 {
    temp = ""; //this line
    Character ch;
```

---

**A future hint**

Do not put variables as class members (fields) if you do not plan to use them in other methods/read the by other classes. Class members are used only for states. Localize all your variables inside the method.

```
public static class RevString {

    public String revString(String str)
    {
        int strLength=str.length();
        System.out.println("length- "+strLength);

        String reversed=str;
        if(strLength!=0)
        { 
            Character ch=str.charAt(strLength-1);          
            String temp=""+ch;                        
            String substr=str.substring(0,strLength-1); 
            if(substr.equals("")){reversed=temp; return reversed;}
            return temp+revString(substr);  
        }
        return reversed;            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you use your variables as class variables, ie *substr, temp, strLength, reversed* should be inside *revString()*.
Then it works.

fixed:

```
public class RevString {


public String revString(String str) {
    String substr="";
    String temp="";
    int strLength=0;
    String reversed="";
    Character ch;
    strLength=str.length();
    System.out.println("length- "+strLength);

    if(strLength!=0)
    { 
        ch=str.charAt(strLength-1);          
        temp=temp+ch;                        
        substr=str.substring(0,strLength-1); 
        if(substr.equals("")){reversed=temp; return reversed;}
        return temp+revString(substr);  
    }
    return reversed;         
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   RevString rev=new RevString();
   System.out.println("reversed string- "+rev.revString("PAWAN"));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying recursion , then you can simplify your method a bit :

```
public String reverseString(String r){
   if (r.length()<2){
       return r;
   }
   else {
       return r.charAt(r.length()-1)+ reverseString(r.substring(0,r.length()-1));
   }
}
```

If you want to use the current method , then keep the below variables (which you have declared as instance variables) in method local scope .

```
Character ch;
String substr="";
String temp="";
int strLength=0;
String reversed="";
```

Answer (score 0):

The temp variable contains already the completely reversed String. If you replace

```
return temp+revString(substr);
```

with

```
return temp;
```

your code works correctly.

And @sotix is of course right: you should not use member variables like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use class attributes for local variables.

If you run your code you will obtain:

```
N + 
NA +
NAW +
NAWA +
NAWAP
=
NNANAWNAWANAWAP
```

Because temp is shared for each call. 
Put your declaration of substr, temp, strLength, reversed at the start of revString().

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RevString {

    private String substr="";
    private String temp="";
    private static int strLength=0;
    private String reversed="";

   public String revString(String str)
    {
        Character ch;

        strLength=str.length();
        System.out.println("length- "+strLength);

        if(strLength!=0)
        { 
            ch=str.charAt(strLength-1);
            if(temp.length()==str.length())
                return temp;
            temp=temp+ch;                        
            substr=str.substring(0,strLength-1); 

            if(substr.equals("")){reversed=temp; return reversed;}
            temp=temp+revString(substr);  
        }
        return reversed;         
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RevString rev=new RevString ();
       System.out.println("reversed string- "+rev.revString("PAWAN"));
    }


}
```